# TortoiseGit "Stuck" Log Message with SHA-1 0000...0000

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have a "stuck" log message in TortoiseGit. It has no SHA-1 nor action, date or author, just the commit message, no changed files:

```
Revision: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Author:  <>
Date: 01.01.1970 08:00:00
Message:
Working dir changes

0 files changed
----
```

and

```
SHA-1: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

* Working dir changes
0 files changed
```

[image: Screenshot]

I think it's from a commit that I tried to somehow undo and probably messed up. The message does not show up when I check the log with git in the bash. What ever I do with the repository, that message just shows up on top of the list in TortoiseGit Log Messages dialog.

Any idea anyone?

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: @codeWizard it's there after any command. But as the other answers explain, it's a "feature" of TortoiseGit, that entry is always there on top. We just started using Git/TortoiseGit and it got me very confused because I thought I messed up something few days ago when I restructured the code base after migrating from SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top most entry in the log dialog subject "working dir changes" you are referrring to is not a bug and not representing a "commit".

That entry represents the uncommitted changes in the working tree and should show the same changed files as the commit dialog. it is inserted so that you also operate the working tree state (e.g., add files to index, diff or stash them).

Comment: Arrgh... it would have been so easy, but I did not google for "Working dir changes" as I was sure that was my comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is not a commit, it is just TortoiseGit's way of representing changes in your working directory. So no need to worry.